# Как сделать полосу прокрутки у слик слайдера вместо навигационных точек

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста!!!
ОЧЕНЬ надо сделать полосу прокрутки у слайдера!!!
Использую slick slider

Стандартная разметка

```
<div class="slick-slider">
  <div> Слайд1</div>
  <div> Слайд2</div>
  <div> Слайд3</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slick-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
});
```

Надо чтобы вместо навигационных кнопок была полоса прокрутки.
Вот как здесь:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Именно полосу прокрутки или просто индикатор положения слайдера со скользящим блоком?

Comment: да, именно полосу прокрутки, чтобы ползунок можно было двигать и  слайды прокручивать